# MySQL: compress data in one column when using LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, csv, blob

In a MySQL database, I am using `BLOB` fields to store some compressed data from potentially long strings of text, that I sometimes want displayed to the users of my web application but that will never be used to be searched or anything, the underlying idea being saving on disk space.

I am trying to populate my tables using `LOAD DATA` and tsv files. The problem is, I am using tabulated files containing **text**, but one of the columns (the `BLOB` one) needs to be compressed.

I tried the following, without success. In this example, the `table_name.tsv` tsv file contains the data I want to insert into `table_name`, and the text I want to compress is in columns `col4`.

```
mysql -h <host> -u <user> -p <pwd> <db_name>  --execute="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'table_name.tsv' INTO TABLE table_name(col1, col2, col3, @col4_comp_data) SET col4=COMPRESS(@col4_comp_data) FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES; SHOW WARNINGS"
```

The error I got was:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1
```

Any idea if it is possible to compress data while loading it with `LOAD DATA`?

Comment: what was the error? please provide: sample record, what you did, and the output vs desired. also, welcome to the community!

Comment: Thanks! I added the error I got. The desired output is to have compressed data (using MySQL's `COMPRESS()` function) in column `col4`.

Comment: looks like you need to clear out the tab separation from the unicode. also, please write out what you want a single record to look like in the question rather than your comment.

Comment: Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html for the correct syntax.. `LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES` needs to go before the columns setting part..

Comment: It was indeed simply a problem of order in my statement ... If you want you can submit that as answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the syntax order wrong. 
The `LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES` part need to go before the column setting part.

The correct order is

**BNF (Backus–Naur form) code**

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
    [(col_name_or_user_var
        [, col_name_or_user_var] ...)]
    [SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT},
        [, col_name={expr | DEFAULT}] ...]
```

source http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html.